# Program closes when running Charles proxy

Tags: windows, sniffing, proxy

I came across an program that closes itself when I run Charles proxy and if I'm running charles before the progran it won't run. Anyone know what type of security if this and can it be reversed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely the program simply checks the list of running processes ans identifies Charles by the name of it's executable. Alternatively the program may check the proxy configuration and if it refers to a proxy on localhost it terminates itself. Third option would be to connect to the proxy and execute certain functions that allows to identify the proxy (e.g. error messages).